# Ruby: Getting a value from an array within a class method

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have the following array:

```
matrix = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"]
```

And I've got to fulfill requirements of the following test:

```
it "should get a cell value" do
  @game.clearmatrix
  value = @game.getmatrixvalue(0)
  value.should == "_"
end
```

clearmatrix is another method within the same class (Game):

```
def clearmatrix
  @matrix = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"]
end
```

From what I can gather from the error messages, `getmatrixvalue` needs to be its own method, but I cannot figure out exactly what needs to be inside it. I'm sure this is really simple and I'm missing something easy, but I just can't see it.

Comment: Do you know how to access an array? If so, do that, inside a method. This is too fundamental for Stack Overflow. You should read a Ruby tutorial.

Comment: The [documentation of the Array class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html) may help you with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just accessing an element in an array:

```
def getmatrixvalue(n)
  @matrix[n]
end
```

Keep in mind that Ruby generally avoids methods with the name `get` in them because the accessor/mutator methods do not need get/set prefixes.

It's worth noting you can write this as:

```
@game.matrix[0]
```

Provided you've declared the `matrix` property as accessible:

```
attr_reader :matrix
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I was forgetting the (n) after getmatrixvalue, I feel a bit stupid now...

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines, it seems to me that what we have is the following. (Note that I've renamed some methods, in part changing 'matrix' to 'array', as 'matrix' suggests use of the `Matrix` class. If you can't change those names, so be it.)

```
class Game
  def initialize(size)
    @size = size
    clear_array
  end

  def clear_array
    @array = Array.new(@size) { '_' }
  end

  def array_value(n)
    @array[n]
  end
end

@game = Game.new(9)

...<other statements>...

it "should get a cell value" do
  @game.clear_array
  value = @game.array_value(0)
  value.should == "_"
end
```

Comment: Thanks for responding Cary, but I managed to get it working with tadman's response above. Sadly I can't rename anything in the tests, so I'm afraid I'm stuck with the confusing matrix name!